Restart simulation when slider gain value is adjusted
I've developed simulink model like below:

In the model there is slider gain which can be adjusted in range from 0 to 1.
I'd like to update Scope:

when slider gain is adjusted:

I've watched the video where it worked by default. Lecturer just set up in Scopes options, Time range from 0 to 0.04 and it did update. In my model it doesn't work. How to achieve such reactive simulation?
